# Пара непереведённых сообщений в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

При клике на шестерёнку рядом с трекером привилегии меню на английском:

[image: Track my next privilege/Track a tag badge instead]

А если на ту же кнопку навести, не кликая, то тоже английская надпись:

[image: Choose between tracking...]

В окошке «Выберите ваш следующий знак» recommended не переведено:

[image: recommended]

Не переведена надпись 1 hidden accounts (кстати, забавно, что account**s**, на английском SO корректно в единственном числе):

[image: hidden accounts]

Ещё чтобы два раза не вставать. Во вкладке «все действия / принятые» написано «У вас нет принятых ответов». Звучит будто никто не принимал мои ответы, а на самом деле это значит, что я не принимал ответы на мои вопросы. Стоит написать «Вы не приняли ни одного ответа».

Comment: На сколько я могу видеть, все кроме "recommended" должно быть переведено. Как я вижу строки для "recommended" нет на Transifex. Добавил в базу дефектов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: "recommended" переведено как «рекомендовано», закрываю баг.